# How to power on Asus T100TA laptop that has power button lid removed?

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair, asus-laptop

I have an **Asus T100TA** laptop with a power button lid removed.

[image]

I don't know what to do. I think I should make some connection between the nodes (1,2,3) shown.

I'm looking for making my laptop **power on** (make the button pressed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodes #1 and #3 are the same. To turn on (press the button), connect (short circuit) #2 across either #1 or #3.

Source: [@dudio](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-3017491/power-asus-t100ta-laptop-power-button-lid-removed.html?56fc4ea1b25ac=reload#17739500)